# TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable when running code

Tags: python, api, typeerror

```
import requests
def temp():
  get_weather = requests.get('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=10970,us&appid=50b55ef1602086c74b71f56c6df14996')
  json_weather = get_weather.json
  kelvin = float(json_weather['main']['temp'])
  print(kelvin)
temp()
```

When running this I get TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable

Answer (score 0):

That is because you need
`json_weather = get_weather.json()`

Its a method that parses the json to an object